# Seam between vinyl plank and hardwood

Tags: floor, vinyl-flooring

We want to replace the flooring in our kitchen, and would like to use click-lock vinyl planks for cost and ease of installation. However, I'm unsure how to transition between these and the adjacent hardwood floors (along the blue tape line), where there's no trim to tuck the edge under. I've found linear transition strips, but nothing with a corner/angle. Is the best I can do to adjust the subfloor to make them flush, and butt the edges together?
[image: Floor]

Comment: Measurements would have to be better than perfect for butt joints(Master jointer level).  If the transition strips go where the tape goes, one cut should be better than trying for all the cuts on the flooring.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the vinyl flooring will go above or below the blue tape, but A) You're replacing some beautiful flooring either way, and B) Consider moving the transition to the joint between the vertical boards (where the tape is) and the horizontal boards in the doorway - that would be a natural location for a transition and a transition strip.

Comment: it's not shown in the photo, but there's a less than beautiful strips of plywood a few feet south where we removed a bar.. we're hoping to tie these rooms together a bit by moving the threshold, but the secondary motivation is I plan to move the extra sections to patch that damage.